# How to merge the frame?

Tags: plotting, graphics, frame, testing-and-verification, copy-as

I just write the code following :

```
GraphicsRow[{LogLogPlot[{\[Xi]v1[w, 1], \[Xi]v2[w, 1], \[Xi]v3[w, 
     1]}, {w, 0.01, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Black, Dashed}, Black}, 
   PlotRange -> {0.01, 
     10^4},(*PlotLegends\[Rule]Placed[{"Equation(1)","Equation2",
   "Numerical"},{{0.02,110},{0.30,110}}],*)ImageSize -> Automatic, 
   Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 3/2.5], 
  LogLogPlot[{\[Xi]v1[w, 2], \[Xi]v2[w, 2], \[Xi]v3[w, 2]}, {w, 0.01, 
    1}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Black, Dashed}, Black}, 
   PlotRange -> {0.01, 10^4}, ImageSize -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 3/2.5], 
  LogLogPlot[{\[Xi]v1[w, 3], \[Xi]v2[w, 3], \[Xi]v3[w, 3]}, {w, 0.01, 
    1}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Black, Dashed}, Black}, 
   PlotRange -> {0.01, 10^4}, ImageSize -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 3/2.5]}, Spacings -> 0]
```

to get the three frame like:
[image]

But I want to achieve the following result:
[image]

It seems "Spacing->0" doesn’t work.These three frames can’t fit closely together.

Comment: try ResourceFunction ["PlotGrid"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/)?

Comment: Spacings -> -4 seems to work, but I can not say why.

Comment: yes, "plotGrid'' satisfy my needs perfectly , but I don’t know why my mathematica (version 12.3) can’t find the resources which makes feel annoyed.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.